# Check if at least one object is not zero

Tags: c#

This function need to check that a=b=c=0 or only one is <>0

there is a best way to do this check?

```
void (int p, int a, int s) {
    if ((p != 0 && a != 0) 
        || (p != 0 && s != 0)
        || (a != 0 && s != 0)
        || (a != 0 && s != 0 && p != 0)) throw new Exception("Error please set A or P or S");

}
```

Comment: set a counter to zero. test each of p,a,s in turn incrementing counter if not zero. Check counter for being 0 or 1.

Comment: And what are your criteria for _"best"_? There is no performance issue here I guess, so is it about readability or amount of code or something else?

Comment: Isn't that "at most one" instead of "at least"?

Comment: is that actually an exclusive or?

Comment: Don't do this at all. Only allow setting of one of them at a time and if so, set the other two to 0.

Comment: @Fildor you mean like ignoring the user's previous input without any notification? sounds like a great user experience.

Comment: @RenéVogt Depends, I expect some form of feedback to a UI. Should have added that, yes. You could, however, combine this with an exception, too by checking if one of the other two is already set, before setting the one in question.

Comment: @RenéVogt - to be fair Fildor's solution does seem very much like a set of RadioButtons - with the option of turning all off.

Comment: Yet another alternative would be to have a setter with one value and an indicator for whether it shall be used as a, s or p.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution, without using Linq or any of the overhead that comes with it:

```
public void Check(int p, int a, int s)
{
    var count = 0;
    if (p != 0) count++;
    if (a != 0) count++;
    if (s != 0) count++;
    if (count >= 2)
        Console.WriteLine("Please set only A or P or S or none");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

Working Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ViMmRV

Comment: @InBetween: Isnt the solution counting how many non-zero vaues there are & passing if the are none or just one, if there more than one are none zero then an exception is thrown as required.

Comment: Nice simple solution. Though `if (count > 1)` is probably a more readable way to say "at most one arg can be non-zero".

Answer (score 1):

```
void Method(int p, int a, int s)
{
    if (new [] { p, a, s }.Count(i => i == 0) <= 1)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error please set A or P or S");
    }
}
```

Comment: That won´t check for "exactly one zero".

Comment: Indeed. Basically you'd want to use `Count` instead, and say that the result should be `<= 1`.

Comment: And creating an array to check 3 variables is _"a best way"_ why?

Comment: @RenéVogt because it's concise. For me this is more important than the micro-optimisation of not creating one.

Comment: @RenéVogt, `params` for arguments?

Answer (score 1):

> This function need to check that **a=b=c=0** or only **one <> 0**

If I correctly understand that:

```cs
private void CheckValues(int p, int a, int s)
{
    var values = new[] { p, a, s };

    if (values.Sum() == 0 || values.Count(v => v != 0) == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

Or

```cs
private void CheckValues(params int[] values)
{
    if (values.Sum() == 0 || values.Count(v => v != 0) == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

Thus:

```cs
CheckValues(0, 0, 0); // <- Error
CheckValues(0, 0, 1); // <- Error
CheckValues(0, 1, 2); // <- OK
CheckValues(1, 2, 3); // <- OK
```

Comment: If you look at what causes an exception in the original code, you reversed the criteria though. 0,0,0 and 0,0,1 should give OK, your other two should give an error. It seems as it OP's function can only handle one of the three arguments at once, or none at all.

Comment: @Nyerguds Thank you mate. Actually I look at the first line in my post: _This function need to check that a=b=c=0 or only one <> 0_. What do you suggest to solve the real problem? Would be nice if you post it since I'm here to learn as well.

Comment: Yeah, the mentioned "check" was actually the pass condition; his actual check in code was the fail condition. So OP did make it a bit confusing there. I've encountered this kind of problem professionally, and the solution I came up with was actually the same one that Peter B posted.

Comment: @Nyerguds Agree _OP did make it a bit confusing there_ That's why I mentioned in my post _If I correctly understand that_ I was curious to just understand this puzzle. Thank you mate, I appreciate your explanation.